# (C++) Determine the unmatched regex capture groups

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

I want to check if a password meets the following requirements:

It should:

- contain at least 1 small letter (ASCII 97-122)
- contain at least 1 letter (65-90)
- contain at least 1 digit
- contain at least 1 special character (33-47, 58-64, 91-96, 123-126)
- have a length between 8 and 20 characters

It should also tell me which of these requirements did it not meet.

---

Given the following expression I can validate it with [regex_match()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) from `std::regex` library

```
regex re("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!-/:-@[-`{-~])(\\S){8,20}$");
```

But this way I can only know if it matches or does not, as it returns a `boolean`

Given this, I tried iterating over the `match_results` like below, after adding some capture groups to the expression.

```
std::string str("AAAaaa111$$$");
std::regex rx("^((?=.*[a-z]).*)((?=.*[A-Z]).*)((?=.*[0-9]).*)((?=.*[!-/:-@[-`{-~]).*)(\\S){8,20}$");
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_search(str, mr, rx);

std::cout << "size: " << mr.size() << '\n'; // 6 or 0 only ?
for (int i = 0; i < mr.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "index: " << i << "\t --> \t" << mr.str(i) << endl;
}

if (regex_match(str, rx)) {
    cout << "tests passed" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "tests failed" << endl;
}
```

And it produced the following output:

```
size: 6
index: 0         -->    AAAaaa111$$$
index: 1         -->    AA
index: 2         -->    Aa
index: 3         -->
index: 4         -->
index: 5         -->    $
tests passed
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What I'd like to achieve is to tell which of the groups failed to match. For example for input: `SamplePassword1` only the 4th group would fail to match, as it does not contain a special character. The user could then be notified which specific requirement/s did the password not meet. Accordingly,`SamplePassword1$` would have a match in each of the groups and pass.

Is this task achievable using a single regular expression rather than having a separete one for each of the requirements?

---

I came across a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310947/determine-which-groups-matched-in-regex), but it's in C# .NET and uses named capturing groups.

> ```
> var re = new Regex("((?<a>a)|(?<b>b))");
> var ma = re.Match("a");
> Console.WriteLine("a in a: " + ma.Groups["a"].Success); //true
> Console.WriteLine("b in a: " + ma.Groups["b"].Success); //false
> ```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to tell when you have repeating captures which ones did not match. I believe the result contains only the final repeat's values. I suspect regex isn't well suited for this. I would probably use a bunch of `std::count_if`s

Comment: Do you really have to do this using just one regex? Why not test five different regexes, one for each condition?

Comment: I just thought a single expression would do a better job than multiple ones. I'm currently trying it out to test if there would be any performance gains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::regex rx("^((?=.*[a-z]))?((?=.*[A-Z]))?((?=.*[0-9]))?((?=.*[!-/:-@[-`{-~]))?(\\S){8,20}$");
```

and check with `mr[i].first == str.end()`. [Demo](http://rextester.com/JZR4975)

That said, recall [the saying](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.